# How to automatically run SQL agent job upon failure of other job

Tags: sql-server, sql-agent-job, sql-agent

I have a stored procedure that gets a job name as input and send mail with job history information.
How can I automatically runs this job when other jobs fail?

Is there a way to pass the name (or ID) of the job to this stored procedure?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use SQL Agent tokens to get the name or ID of the currently executing job (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175575(v=sql.105).aspx).

To set this up, do the following:

1. Add new step "Email job history" to the end of your job
2. Change each job step to have an "OnFailure" action of "Go to step: {n} Email job history", where {n} is the step # of the step added above.
3. Use the SQL Agent tokens to get your currently executing `JOBID` and any other info you need.  Example of "Email job history" T-SQL step below, where `msdb.dbo.usp_SQLAgentSendJobStepFailedEmail` would be your procedure name:

Example of "Email job history" T-SQL step:

```
DECLARE @jobid uniqueidentifier, @run_date int, @run_time int, @profile_name sysname;

set @profile_name = 'MyDatabaseMailProfileName';

--USE SQL AGENT "TOKENS" TO GET CURRENT JOB PARAM VALUES
set @jobid = $(ESCAPE_NONE(JOBID));
set @run_date = $(ESCAPE_NONE(STRTDT));
set @run_time = $(ESCAPE_NONE(STRTTM));

EXEC msdb.dbo.usp_SQLAgentSendJobStepFailedEmail @jobid = @jobid, @run_date = @run_date, @run_time = @run_time, @email_profile_name = @profile_name;
```